# Is there any way to dynamically modify dates based on number of days something would take?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-arrayformula, google-sheets-dates

Imagine you're creating a Google Sheet to track all of your tasks, how long they take, and their deadlines:

```
Task                    |Number of days| Start Date | Date Done
Buy plane tickets       |       5      | 15.12.2019 | 20.12.2019
Reserve hotel           |       2      | 21.12.2019 | 23.12.2019
Prepare snacks for trip |       1      | 24.12.2019 | 25.12.2019
Go on trip              |      14      | 26.12.2019 | 10.01.2020
```

Is there any way in Google Sheets to update the dates dynamically if another task is added in the middle?

Say you wanted to add renting a car to the plan, and it will take you five days. Is there any way in google sheets that once you add it, the sheet would automatically update from this:

```
Task                    |Number of days| Start Date | Date Done
Buy plane tickets       |       5      | 15.12.2019 | 20.12.2019
Reserve hotel           |       2      | 21.12.2019 | 23.12.2019
Rent a car              |       5      | 24.12.2019 | 29.12.2019
Prepare snacks for trip |       1      | 24.12.2019 | 25.12.2019
Go on trip              |      14      | 26.12.2019 | 10.01.2020
```

To this?

```
Task                    |Number of days| Start Date | Date Done
Buy plane tickets       |       5      | 15.12.2019 | 20.12.2019
Reserve hotel           |       2      | 21.12.2019 | 23.12.2019
Rent a car              |       5      | 24.12.2019 | 29.12.2019
Prepare snacks for trip |       1      | **30.12.2019** | **31.12.2019**
Go on trip              |      14      | **01.01.2020** | **14.01.2020**
```

Essentially automatically delay all the other tasks based on the newly introduced task?

[Link to Google Sheet with an example of desired behaviour](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qNBFUYRFN4FAhf1P2Y2mTlWzMeMsxTYomLX0UGCd0Vk/edit?usp=sharing)

If there is no way in Google Sheets, is there any other tool you know to do this?

Comment: what's the difference? - https://i.stack.imgur.com/8bmmK.png share a copy of your sheet with example of desired output

Comment: The difference is marked with **  - also, how do I share a sheet?

Comment: just paste sheet url/link into comment or your post and enable sharing in your sheet (top right corner - green share button)

Comment: Done - added the Google Sheet link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

paste in **C4** cell:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(IF(B4:B=""; ;SUMIF(ROW(B3:B); "<="&ROW(B3:B); B3:B)+
 DATEVALUE(C3)); "where Col1 is not NULL"; 0)+ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A"&COUNTA(A4:A))))
```

[image: 0]

---

paste in **D3** cell:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(A3:A); TO_DATE(C3:C+B3:B); ))
```

[image: 0]

### [spreadsheet demo](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1RGKnW3LRmz_oeD2PqwE8noLU00RP-ZQ_4N69p7kbFzk/edit#gid=0)

Comment: This is perfect and exactly what I was looking for - thanks @user()!